# Function is running before scope and view has loaded

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive which calls a jQuery plugin on the element.

On initial page load, it does not work as it appears the function is running before the data and scope have loaded.

Here is the directive:

```
app.directive('hotelExperiences', function($timeout) {
return{
  link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
      $timeout(function(){
        element.flickity({
            cellAlign: 'center',
            contain: true,
            wrapAround: true,
            freeScroll: true,
            cellSelector: '.experience'
        });
    });
}
```

} 
});

The data is being loaded from a JSON file - which is loading fine and works.  It is just the function is saying there are no elements as it is running before the scope has finished.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear which data you're talking about, but if you want your directive to execute only once some data is available in the scope, just use ng-if:

```
<div hotel-experiences ng-if="data"></div>
```

Comment: Easy solution.  Can't believe i didn't think of that. MANY thanks.